# ionic react getting screen width dynamically

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

i am using ionic react and struggling on how to use calcWidth to get the width dynamically. Currently i am using something like below

```
width={310}
```

which gives 310 px in my react component i am using. the documentation suggest to use calcWidth but does not explain how. I see some examples to use Dimensions but seems i could not use that with ionic react.

i tried plain

```
width={calcWidth}
```

but that does not work as it will need the width property.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can obtain the screen width by using the window:

```
window.innerWidth
```